# Frontpage Admin Bar Disappeared

Tags: plugins, multisite, admin, admin-bar

I am on a multisite network. Recently my frontpage admin bar dissappeared but continued to show at backend. I disabled all the plugins, changed theme to twenty ten and twenty twelve also, but no success. But it starts showing when i change name of plugins folder to something else, but it doesn't when i network deactivate all plugins without changing name of plugins folder. I think network disabling all and/or changing plugins folder name is same thing so it should work by both ways. But admin bar only shows hen i change plugins folder name to something else, but not by disabling all plugins network wide. Please help ASAP.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without more information or hands-on debugging. Had you tried removing plugins one by one to narrow it down?

Comment: I did but still no success.

Comment: this may be your css  problum kindly check the dashbord css add frontend with each other  for strip

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue and solved it by addig [`wp_footer();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) function in `footer.php`. Please make sure that you have [`wp_footer();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) in `footer.php`.

Comment: I doubt that's it.